# php через консоль windows

Tags: php, windows-7

Приветствую. Требуется развернуть symfony на windows. Так как там используется много консольных команд, следовательно будет задействована консоль. Возникли проблемы с запуском: "php" не является внутренней или внешней командой... в переменной path путь добавлен, при выводе через set он виден. При выводе echo %php% выводится %php% а не его значение. В чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы не хотите особо мучатся с настройками есть вариант. Вы можете использовать веб-сервер XAMPP. Там есть shell console через которую вы сможете без проблем работать с symfony а также полностью настрой сервер под себя.

https://www.apachefriends.org/ru/index.html

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: я так понимаю в этом случае xampp будет использоваться как основной сервер а не встроенный artisan?

Comment: @Vadim.K, На скриншоте показано где находиться консоль а дальше думаю все понятно

Answer (score 0):

Для начала Вам нужно указать в переменной окружения Windows [PATH](http://www.java.com/ru/download/help/path.xml) путь, где находится Ваш php (релог или перезагрузка). После этого Windows будет знать, что такое php.

Очень хорошее решение в плане эмулятора сервера: 
[Open Server](http://open-server.ru). Работаю в нем с Symfony 2. В нем есть все, что нужно и даже, чего не нужно ).

Касательно Вашего вопроса, он позволяет привязаться к переменной окружения Windows PATH. И тогда консоль, к. в него встроена (очень, кстати, удобная) будет спокойно обращаться с php.